# Merge two excel files using a common column

Tags: vba, excel

I have two excel sheets. I have to merge the two such that the values in one match with the other. For eg.

```
The first excel,    the 2nd excel

1  t                 1   tes1
2  5                 3   tes3
3  t                 4   tes4
4  g
```

Notice that in the first column of the 2nd excel, 2 is missing, so I want the first excel to look like this,

```
1 tes1 t
2      5 
3 tes3 t
4 tes4 g
```

I am new to excel. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you want a relational database (e.g. Access) rather than a spreadsheet. Either way, this question is better asked on SuperUser.com.

Comment: Thanks buddy..I have asked this there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub left_join()
Dim res As Variant
Dim i As Long, lastUsedRowSh1 As Long, lastUsedRowSh2 As Long
Dim cell As Range
Sheets(3).Cells.ClearContents
Sheets(1).Range("a:b").Copy Destination:=Sheets(3).Range("a1")
Sheets(3).Columns(2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
lastUsedRowSh1 = Sheets(1).Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastUsedRowSh2 = Sheets(2).Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
i = 1
For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("a1:a" & lastUsedRowSh1)
    On Error Resume Next
    res = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Value, Sheets(2).Range("a1:b" & lastUsedRowSh2), 2, 0)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Sheets(3).Range("b" & i).Value = res
            i = i + 1
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

You can even solve with a simple formula.

Foglio1

```
A   B
1   t
2   5
3   t
4   g
```

Foglio2

```
A   B
1   tes1
3   tes3
4   tes4
```

Foglio3

Copy the content of Foglio1 in Foglio3, then run this formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Foglio1!A1,Foglio2!$A$1:$B$3,2,0))=TRUE,"",VLOOKUP(Foglio1!A1,Foglio2!$A$1:$B$3,2,0))
```

and drag it down. Regards.

[image]

Comment: I dont even know what to do with the first portion of the answer, lol..can u explain in detail what to do with it

Comment: You can use ADO and SQL with Excel. A Left Join would work very well here. More info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819, also in StackOverflow.